# getting undefined while accessing this object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 objects OldAnswer and NewAnswer. I am trying to convert array of OldAnswer objects to array of NewAnswer objects.

```
export class AnswerComponent implements OnInit {


answers: OldAnswer[] = [/* some data  */];

newanswers: NewAnswer[];

constructor() {


    this.answers.forEach(function (answer) {

        answer.answers.forEach(function (a){

            for (var key in a) {
                text = // some logic"";     
            }
            // exception in below line
        this.newanswers.push({id: answer.observationId,answer: text});
        });
    });

    }

}
```

but I am getting "*Can't call newanswers on undefined*". Why is `this` object `undefined` here and not while accessing answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Cause of the issue :

you used `forEach` with `function()`

### Solution :

Use arrow functions to define your functions in the `forEach`s :

```
this.answers.forEach((answer) => {

    answer.answers.forEach((a) => {
```

### Why arrow functions solve the problem :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this

> Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value
>   (based on how function was called, a new object in the case of a
>   constructor, **undefined in strict mode function calls**, the base object
>   if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to
>   be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.

(emphasis mine).

Since Angular / TypeScript will generate strict mode Javascript, the `this` will  `undefined` in the body of a `function() {}`, it will not reference the object instance of your class anymore.

Note: there are other "good?-old JavaScript ways" to solve this issue, but the arrow function is really the usual way of doing this now and in most situations like this in TypeScript / Angular / ES6.

### Also initialize your array before calling `push()` on it

However, you will also experience the problem that `newanswers` is also undefined (at least it isn't in the sample you provided, so as Simonare noticed, you should also get it initialized as an empty array `[]`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

adding a reference link for the ES6 arrow function syntax and explanation as to why this is necessary

Comment: @ArronMcCrory yes thank you, I didn't elaborate when I wrote it. I edited my answer to incorporate the link, and added some explanations in the answer itself

Answer (score 2):

you declared array but did not initialize. Fix:

```
newanswers: NewAnswer[] = [];
```

Also you need to use arrow function so that your  scope will not change

```
this.answers.forEach(answer => { 
  answer.answers.forEach( (a) => { 
    for (var key in a) { 
      text = // some logic""; 
    } // exception in below line 

    this.newanswers.push({id: answer.observationId,answer: text}); 
}); }); }
```

Comment: Seems by OP's error message that `this` is undefined here,